# How to add objects into an array through loop in Javascript $.each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am a beginner programmer trying to transfer four properties from my JSONP array into a new array for every item.

```
$.ajax({
    url: etsyURL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.ok) {
            var a = (data.results);
            //create a parent array to store all objects
            var bigarray = [];

            $.each(a, function(i, item) {
                //assign values from response to variables
                var atitle = item.title;
                var aurl = item.url;
                var aimg = item.Images[0].url_75x75;
                var aprice = item.price;

                //create an object
                var object = {
                    title: atitle,
                    url: aurl,
                    img: aimg,
                    price: aprice
                };

                //add the object into big array for every each item, unsure                                             
            })
        }
    }
});
```

My end goal is to get `bigarray` to get all all items in objects like below:

```
bigarray = [{title:"xbox", url:"www.web.com", pic:"www.pic.com/w.png",price:"100"}, {title:"ps4", url:"www.web.com", pic:"www.pic.com/p.png",price:"110"}]
```

**Question**
**1.** How do I add objects based on the number of items in the array?
**2.** Any other methods are welcomed, I will accept the answer even if $.even is replaced with a for loop.

Comment: `bigarray[] = object;`

Comment: if `data.results` is an array you don't need `$.each()` -> [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), otherwise use [`$.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) (+ [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/))

Comment: Use the push function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *push()* to add item into the array and you can even modify your code as below

```
$.ajax({
    url: etsyURL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.ok) {
            var a = (data.results);
            //create a parent array to store all objects
            var bigarray = [];

            $.each(a, function(i, item) {
                //add the object into big array for every each item, unsure 
                bigarray.push({
                   title: item.title,
                    url: item.url,
                    img: item.Images[0].url_75x75,
                    price: item.price
                });

            })
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the push method, which can be used to add a value to the end of an array.

```
bigArray = []; // create the array
object = {foo: 'bar'}; // create an object
bigArray.push({object}); // push the object onto the end of the array
```